# Printf outputs the same array twice

Tags: c, file-io

My main problem is that when I print from the struct Item s, s.name is printed twice.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct Item{
    char code[5];
    char name[40];
};

int main(){
    FILE *f;
    struct Item s;

    //Open file
    f = fopen("ex.txt", "r");

    //Read from file
    fscanf(f, "%5c;%[a-zA-Z ]\n", s.code, s.name);

    //Print from file
    printf("%s %s", s.code, s.name); //Main problem here
    fclose(f);
}
```

Input (ex.txt):

```
AB011;Hello World
```

Output should be:

```
AB011 Hello World
```

But instead it's:

```
AB011Hello World Hello World
```

What is going on here?

**Additional Notes**: I need to use fscanf for this one so that I can learn how it works.

Comment: what is gst_file? Shouldn't you read from the file you've opened?

Comment: `%s` : argument need  null-terminator.

Comment: @JewelThief Yeah, sorry about that. Just corrected it.

Comment: Bean-counting again:(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the call to `fscanf` you are using

```
"%5c;%[a-zA-Z ]\n"
```

as the format specifier. The `%5c` part of the format specifier reads 5 characters to `s.code`. That does not leave room for a terminating null character.

Using that as an argument to `printf` with `%s` specifier leads to undefined behavior. `%s` needs a null terminated string.

You should change the size of `code` to use 6 characters, and then terminate it with a null character after the `fscanf` line.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct Item{

    /// CHANGED HERE 
    char code[6];
    char name[40];
};

int main(){
    FILE *f;
    struct Item s;

    //Open file
    f = fopen("ex.txt", "r");

    //Read from file
    fscanf(f, "%5c;%[a-zA-Z ]\n", s.code, s.name);

    /// CHANGED HERE 
    s.code[5] = '\0';

    //Print from file
    printf("%s %s", s.code, s.name);
    fclose(f);
}
```

Comment: So the main problem is that I need an extra space at the end to denote the null character?

Comment: @R Sahu Okay, now I get it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Steve, you are welcome. I am glad I was able to help.

Comment: There should not be `\n` on the end of fscanf format string. Also the behaviour of `-` inside `%[` is implementation-defined  (not necessarily a regular expression as OP seems to expect)

Comment: @M.M I know that the behaviour of %[ is not that of regex, but that of range of characters. And I need '\n' at the end of fscanf because the code before this had '\n' of its fprintf.

Comment: @Steve it might not be range of characters either, depends on what C library you happen to be using.  `\n` in scanf does NOT mean "read a newline in the input".

Answer (score 2):

1. If you are storing 5 characters in `code` the size has to be six bytes, including the `\0` terminator.
2. For scanf `%[5]c` - reads exactly 5 characters and does not add a terminating `\0`.

> If a width other than 1 is specified, the function reads exactly width characters and stores them in the successive locations of the array passed as argument. No null character is appended at the end.

What you need to do is add the `\0` yourself at the end

```
//Read from file
fscanf(f, "%5c;%[a-zA-Z ]\n", s.code, s.name);
s.code[5] = '\0';
```